# Visual Basic Running external .exe issue

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I am currently working on a project and have found that using the Process.Start and shell commands to run other existing programs is being problematic. What happens is that when I click the button in my program to launch the other exe file it loads the program but not correctly, iv seen this behavior in two external programs of mine one fails to update when run through my program but on its own works fine the other fails to load up the interface correctly and gives me an error.

The error tells me it cant find the resources it relies on to function so can anyone tell me why it does this and a possible solution as iv tried all the startup codes I know: Start, Process.Start and shell?

EDIT
I also found that if I place my exe in the same folder as the program I want to run it works fine but this is not suitable for my project so any workarounds?

Solution:
Thanks for all your help I needed to set the working directory, beginners mistake :)

```
Dim filePath As String = "C:\Program Files\Example\Example.exe"  
Dim psi As New ProcessStartInfo(filePath)    

psi.WorkingDirectory = IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(filePath)  Process.Start(psi)
```

Comment: This is too vague, what is the error, what kind of a process is it? Just a general .exe is not enough information to understand this.

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure what type of .exe it is other than its a standalone windows form application and the other program i tried was a console application.
The error i got on one of the programs was part of the program itself and the error said the program was missing an exe file to make it function correctly.

Comment: Still it's not easy to answer this given the information. You can try running the .exe standalone and see if it works first.

Comment: If i run the program on its own its fine and functions correctly but as soon as I use the Process.Start in my program to launch the exe from a different directory from my executable the other programs fails to function correctly. I think its to do with the program somehow being moved away from its resources because it displays the same behavior if i move the program to the desktop away from its other necessary files.

Comment: Can you give us an example of the code that should start your .exe?

Comment: heh Of course you need to run the exe in the same folder... the application need its dependencies to execute properly. Have you tried with a shortcut?

Comment: Thanks allot for all your help iv learned something new today :) I needed to set the working directory...........

`Dim filePath As String = "C:\Program Files\Example\Example.exe"
 Dim psi As New ProcessStartInfo(filePath)
 
 psi.WorkingDirectory = IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(filePath)
 Process.Start(psi)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to define a WorkingDirectory

```
var proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
proc.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = "The Location of the process";
proc.Start("the process");
```

Comment: Not only the working directory but also the filename. 
 
Dim Proc As New Process()

Proc.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = LocalDir

Proc.StartInfo.FileName = varFileName

Proc.Start()